# How to do blurry search key name recursively in jq

Tags: jq

I don't like the original inspect method to search specific field on Docker, so I use jq to find the config I want, for example:

```
docker inspect test | jq '.[].NetworkSettings
docker inspect test | jq '.. | .NetworkSettings? | objects'
```

both scripts can get the results:

```
{
  "Bridge": "",
  "SandboxID": "4951989910db53c8bb8368add9ddcdf0e69cd14a9ff09ef95402850f24c5de08",
  "HairpinMode": false,
  "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
  "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
  "Ports": {},
  "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/4951989910db",
  "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
  "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
  "EndpointID": "",
  "Gateway": "",
  "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
  "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
  "IPAddress": "",
  "IPPrefixLen": 0,
  "IPv6Gateway": "",
  "MacAddress": "",
  "Networks": {
    "test_default": {
      "IPAMConfig": null,
      "Links": null,
      "Aliases": [
        "f3df83d51385",
        "test"
      ],
      "NetworkID": "4b09f5c3a82cb7c9770efec1fc818eb071cf707bd60ec96202664d5282d73b6c",
      "EndpointID": "",
      "Gateway": "",
      "IPAddress": "",
      "IPPrefixLen": 0,
      "IPv6Gateway": "",
      "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
      "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
      "MacAddress": "",
      "DriverOpts": null
    }
  }
}
```

but is base on I totally type the config name `NetworkSettings` correctly, is there a way to do blurry search key recursively and case insensitive by jq? like `docker inspect test | jq '.. | search(. | match("network";"i") | objects'`, it won't work, just an example.

Answer (score 2):

With this def:

```
def blurry($f):
  ($f | ascii_upcase) as $ucf
  | to_entries[]
  | select((.key|ascii_upcase) == $ucf)
  | .value;
```

you could write:

```
.. | blurry("NetworkSettings")? | objects
```

### Blurrier

Blurriness having many shades, you could go further, e.g.:

```
def veryBlurry($f):
  ($f | ascii_upcase) as $ucf
  | to_entries[]
  | select(.key | ascii_upcase | index($ucf))
  | .value;
```

You could continue along this path, e.g. using regular expressions.